# Is there a way to ignore empty lines in the ndiff lib and to print only the + and the number of the line? PYTHON

Tags: python, regex, python-re, txt, difflib

So guys, here is my code:

```
import io
import difflib
import re

with io.open('textest.txt', mode="r", encoding="utf_8_sig") as file:
    lines1 = file.readlines()
    

with io.open('minitext.txt', mode="r", encoding="utf_8_sig") as file:
    lines2 = file.readlines()

def prefilter(line):
    return re.sub("\s+"," ",line.strip())


for d in difflib.ndiff([prefilter(x) for x in lines1],[prefilter(x) for x in lines2]):
    print(d)
```

the textest.txt is the full song and the minitext.txt is just a part of it. The output is this (I know, it's a justin bieber song, it's just an example)

```
+ somethin' I don't wanna hold back
- For all the times that you rained on my parade
- And all the clubs you get in using my name
- You think you broke my heart, oh, girl, for goodness' sake
- You think I'm crying on my own, well, I ain't
- And I didn't wanna write a song
- 'Cause I didn't want anyone thinkin' I still care, I don't, but
- You still hit my phone up
- And baby, I'll be movin' on
- And I think you should be somethin' I don't wanna hold back
  Maybe you should know that
  My mama don't like you and she likes everyone
  And I never like to admit that I was wrong
  And I've been so caught up in my job
  Didn't see what's going on, but now I know
+
+
+
  I'm better sleeping on my own
+ 'Cause if you like the wa
- 'Cause if you like the way you look that much
- Oh, baby, you should go and love yourself
- And if you think that I'm still holdin' on to somethin'
```

The thing is: I wanted to print only the + (The different lines on the lines2, that is the minitext.txt), and the number of the line which is different. I also wanted to ignore the completely empty lines so the output is just like:

- somethin' I don't wanna hold back (Number of line in minitext.txt)
- 'Cause if you like the wa (Number of line in minitext.txt)

or anything similiar. Is there a way I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

if you go into difflib.py in your system (`difflib.__file__` (get path for this module in your system))
you find that ndiff  ->  `return Differ(linejunk, charjunk).compare(a, b)`

after that inside Differ class check compare function....

this module work with _dump for yield (tag + string -->>> you see in print)
`we overwrite this function for our own purpose`

1. we filter tag(we need + tag)
2. filter string (we need not empty)

you can check(source code) and retrieve everything that you like.

```
import difflib


# over write Differ class (difflib.ndiff work with compare function that exist in this class)
class Differ(difflib.Differ):
    # this function used for + tag
    def _dump(self, tag, x, lo, hi):
        """Generate comparison results for a same-tagged range."""
        for i in range(lo, hi):
            # only yield if tag == "+"
            if tag == '+':
                # if second list not empty yield result
                if x[i] != "":
                    # change format (item of second list string, i==index (number line start from 0))
                    yield '%s(%s)' % (x[i], i)


# example of two list of string
a = ["first", "second", "three", "four"]
b = ["number_one", "second", "number_three", "four"]

differ_object = Differ()
result = differ_object.compare(a, b)
for _ in result:
    print(_)
# result
"""
number_one(0)
number_three(2)
"""
```